# ubuntu 14.04 - Unknown Display - Resolution limited by 1360 * 768

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have a 2nd monitor (Samsung) but Ubuntu cannot detect the monitor as well as the best resolution (1680*1050). So far the max. resolution is 1360*768.

[image: screenshot - display settings]

One thing I tried is to use “addmode” but received the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

I have also tried to update the NVIDA driver but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? If yes, what was it?